# Is there a better syntax to obtain the derivative of a function as a function/operator? (e.g. for simple plotting of derivtives of functions, etc.)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, replacement, syntax

When trying to plot a derivative of a function, (I take `Sin` as a simple example), the naive approach

```
Plot[D[Sin[x], x], {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

fails. One can work around this by a replacement rule

```
Plot[D[Sin[y], y] /. y -> x, {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

which then indeed plots the derivative, i.e. the `Cos.

This is an example of the general syntax "problem", that if I have a function `f`, say of one variable, and I want to obtain `f'` as well as a function, then I have to perform this cumbersome definition of `f'` with that replacement rule:

```
fprim[x_]:=D[f[y], y]/.y → x
```

I know that this works, and in this sense that is not an actual problem. However I always thought this a bit cumbersome that one has to introduce an additional dummy variable, and from a mathematical perspective I would rather have the derivative to be a function by default, to which arguments can be applied.

**So the question is:** Is there a better syntax to obtain `f'` as a function than the one I used in the examples above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Derivative`

```
Plot[ Derivative[1][Sin ][x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

or `Evaluate`

```
Plot[Evaluate[D[Sin[x], x]], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Comment: I like this much better, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Or `Plot[Sin'[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`